# Store registration ID on shared preferences GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to integrate `GCM` into my app. I read at many places that in `onRegistered()`, we should store the `regId` on shared preferences. Can anyone tell, why is there a need to store the ID on shared preferences. I saw `GCMRegistrar.java` code and internally it is doing this mechanism. Then why there is a need to store the ID on shared preferences manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You dont need to save it in sharedPreference.Use the following lines

```
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());
if (regId.equals("")) {
      GCMRegistrar.register(this,SENDER_ID);
 } else {
        //Already registered
 }
```

If the registartion id is null you can go for registration..

Comment: Anyone looking at this. Don't use it. GCMRegistrar is deprecated. You should in fact save it in sharedPrefs. Look at the guide here https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Answer (score 4):

This method is used for not registering device every time.

1. If you use gcm-client.jar then you don't need to worry about it. This is implemented in this jar file.
2. If you want to implement it yourself then you can

   - save registrationId using SharedPreferences or save it on the DB or file system etc.
   - not save registrationId and register device every time.However, this is not a good design choice, since it requires one more iteration (getting registration id from google) when application started.

Comment: Thanks..This was my doubt.. I'm using GCM.jar. So I guess I don't need to worry about this.

Answer (score 3):

Its simple. Don't make it complex.
AS your device registered with GSM, it will not automatically get Notification.
You have to register your device with 3rd party server which needs your registration ID.

As the id was stored in pref, it will not register device again and again.

Comment: Is it that simple ? nothing to do anything else?

Answer (score 1):

This is a design choice. You may want to store it in the `SharedPreferences`, in a file or in a SQLite database. It really depends on the application and what you are trying to accomplish with it.

As for why the `GCMRegistrar.java` example stores it in `SharedPreferences` - I think it is done, because there is a need to invalidate/remove the locally stored Device ID when the app is updated, which is easily done by deleting the primitive data, saved on the device. Much easier and resource sparing (no more than 3-4 lines of code required) than querying a database or deleting files via `rmfile()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to register it by your own to use it in the future for example to talk to your push server specifying your regID.